# Retrieve data from an object in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object (Universities) which contains list items (Campuses, Courses, Students, etc..).

```
public class Universities
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Campus> CampusList { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Course> CourseList { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Student> StudentList { get; set; }
}

public class Campus
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I need to know whether or not any list item has error message.

For example, I need to capture all the error message using LINQ or other alternative methods.

```
Universities 
   - CampusList
   - CourseList
      ErrorMessage
   - StudentList
      ErrorMessage
```

Since I am not able to write a query such as `Universities.Any()`

I cannot write a for loop because there is not `Count` extension for the object such as `Universities.Count`

I could able to access each list item `Universities.Students` or `Universities.Courses`, etc..

Any guideline or suggestion?

Comment: You answered your own question, use the Students and Courses properties.

Comment: @Crowcoder However, I have only provided a subset of objects' list items. What if I have 30 list items in the object. Should I have to write a 30 queries for each of them? Such as `Univerisites.Courses.Any(x=> x.Error)`.. I believe there might be a better/efficient way of handling.

Comment: Do you mean 30 lists or 30 items in a list?  Please edit your question so it more accurately communicates what you're trying to do.

Comment: So you want something like `Universities.SelectMany(u => u.CourseList).SelectMany(c => c.Errors)`?

Comment: @DavidG, there is no `SelectMany` extenstion for `Universities`.

Comment: You could add a method to the University class that checks for the errors; no need to make callers do the logic in multiple places.

Comment: @Amy, I mean `campuslist, courselist, studentlist, buildinglist, teacherlist. etc...`

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't read it properly. Try `Universities.CourseList.SelectMany(c => c.Errors)`

Comment: If this is an assignment, I'm guessing you're supposed to implement an interface, since it is crying out for it.

Comment: @DavidG, should I have to check each list item like that? what if you have tens of list items in the object?

Comment: @JohnWu, any guideline or sample would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have tens of `List`s in the class, then you need tens of checks unless you want to do something really not recommended, like reflection. How are the various `List`s initialized? Also, what type of answer do you expect? a flat `List<ErrorMessage>`?

Answer (score 2):

So the correct method would be to create an interface to reflect the commonality of objects that contain an `ErrorMessage` property:

```
interface IErrorMessage {
    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement the interface on each object:

```
public class Campus : IErrorMessage {
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add a private helper method and a public method to return `ErrorMessage`s to the `Universities` class:

```
private List<string> GetErrorMessagesFromList<T>(List<T> aList) where T : IErrorMessage {
    return aList.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ErrorMessage)).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
}

public List<string> GetErrorMessages() {
    return GetErrorMessagesFromList(CampusList)
            .Concat(GetErrorMessagesFromList(CourseList))
            .Concat(GetErrorMessagesFromList(StudentList))
            .ToList();
}
```

Then, given a `Universities` object, you can call `GetErrorMessages`.

However, you can also use reflection and extract everything at runtime, which is hard to follow, complicated, and undoubtedly slower, but can be done by adding a method to the `Universities` class:

```
public List<string> GetErrorMessagesByReflection() {
    bool IsList(Type aType) => aType.IsGenericType && aType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<>));

    var errorMessages = new List<string>();

    var props = this.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => IsList(p.PropertyType));

    foreach (var prop in props) {
        var aList = prop.GetValue(this) as IEnumerable;
        foreach (var anItem in aList) {
            var possibleErrorMessage = anItem.GetType().GetProperty("ErrorMessage").GetValue(anItem) as string;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(possibleErrorMessage))
                errorMessages.Add(possibleErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    return errorMessages;
}
```